# C++ library for time zone handling

Tags: c++, timezone

I'm looking for a simple C++ library that allows me to convert timezone descriptions like "America/New_York" into an offset to GMT.

I'm looking for a lightweight library to add to an existing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used it but I think boost date time can do this:
[boost::date_time - local_time database](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.tz_database)

Comment: boost worked nicely, once I realized that the necessary timezone database wasn't included in the openSuSE distribution of boost and I fetched the source.

Comment: Boost's database is way too simple and small compared to the official release of the TZ database by IANA.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Roguewave libraries for c++.
http://www.roguewave.com/products/sourcepro/